# How to adjust width of form in css with window resize?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, width

I have the following form:

```
<form id="search_form" class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="GET" action="/search/">
    <div class="input-group" id="search_form_container">
        <input type="text" id="search_box" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search" value="{% block srch_val %}{% endblock %}">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
#search_form {
    position: absolute;
    left: 180px;
}
```

I want to create a search form that will adjust its width according to the window width while resizing. For example please check [www.amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try implementing [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), as their **row** and **col** style layout could handle this nicely.

Here's how your page could look...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Example Site</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/   bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Wrapper -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Col 1 -->
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                Example
            </div>
            <!-- Col 2 -->
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <!-- Form -->
                <form id="search_form" class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="GET" action="/search/">
                    <div class="input-group" id="search_form_container">
                        <input type="text" id="search_box" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search" value="{% block srch_val %}{% endblock %}" style="width: 100%">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- Col 3 -->
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                Example
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox!

It is pure css property supported long time ago. Good thing is that you dont absolutely necessary need separate framework to make responsive html! You can use plain css:

```
#search_form {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    padding:0px 5% 0px 180px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#search_form_container { display:flex; flex-direction:row; }

#search_form input[type=text] { flex-grow:1; }
#search_form_container > span { flex-grow:0;  }
```

Please, note that exact space offsets and widths you have to determine your self, based on your design etc. But the idea of flexbox and how it helps to make responsive html elements is visible.

```css
#search_form {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    padding:0px 5% 0px 180px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#search_form_container { display:flex; flex-direction:row; }

#search_form input[type=text] { flex-grow:1; }
#search_form_container > span { flex-grow:0;  }
```

```html
<form id="search_form" class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="GET" action="/search/">
    <div class="input-group" id="search_form_container">
        <input type="text" id="search_box" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search" value="{% block srch_val %}{% endblock %}">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```